# Load remote image in my own domain without copying

Tags: php

I want to load an external image in my domain without copying the image on my server as if it looks I am hosting this image.

I have tried it using copying it to my server via curl. But I want it without copying. i.e. external image location is http://example.com/image.jpg

Now i want to load this image as http://examplemydomain.com/image.jpg without copying the file in my server. Any suggestion how to achieve this in php?

Comment: Simple asnwer - it is complicated. Complicated answer - use some php script as `src` of image, that script will get contents of an image file on remote server and output it.

Comment: Lets try the complicated answer first. ;)

Comment: It's not complicated at all, a simple .htaccess line can visually redirect any remote host image/url to your host, but first, **how will this affect the original hosts copyright**?

Answer (score 0):

At my workplace we use sopmething like this. Notice: it's larger, because the images are resized to fit 150x150 square *avatar*. Just remove that part and use `width`, `$height` instead of `$newwidth` to get original. I would remove it myself, but it's Christmas morning and I'm just not in the mood.

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^photo/(.*)$ photo.php?fn=$1 [QSA,L]
```

*.photo.php*

```
<?php

// Images (not the safest way to check though )
$allowed_ext = array(
    'gif' => 'image/gif',
    'png' => 'image/png',
    'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
    'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg'
);
$square_size = 150;

// Get file data
$file_name = trim($_GET['fn']);
$file_path = 'http://example.com/' . urlencode($file_name);
list($width, $height) = @getimagesize($file_path);

// Do something ONLY if file is found
if (!empty($width) && !empty($height)) {
    $ext = pathinfo($file_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    // We accept only predefined images. if not image extension - DIE!
    if (empty($allowed_ext[$ext])) {
        die();
    } else {
        $mtype = $allowed_ext[$ext]; // Set our predefined meme types ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
    }

    // Get new image ratio
    $ratio = ($width > $height) ? $square_size / $width : $square_size / $height;

    // Resize only if original is larger then allowed
    if ($ratio < 1) {
        $new_width = $width * $ratio;
        $new_height = $height * $ratio;
    } else {
        $new_width = $width;
        $new_height = $height;
    }

    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_path);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    // Output
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mtype);
    imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
}
die;
```

When set up, you just open `http://examplemydomain.com/photo/image.jpg` and it will load the remote image.

Comment: Hey thanx for your answer. But i dont need to customize the image. I have achieved this by a simple header function. But i would really want to know how to achieve this only by using .htaccess as u said.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific directory structure for your images, ex: they all exist under /public/images, then you can edit your server settings (httpd.conf or apache2.conf depending on your server) and add a proxy similar to the below:

```
ProxyPass /public/images http://examplemydomain.com/public/images
```

remember to restart apache / httpd after doing the changes